# Word VBA .doc files prompting user on close

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a bunch of word documents in a folder. Some are .docx files and some are .doc files. My code works with the .docx files but every time the file is a .doc file it prompts me to save. I am working with over 5k .doc files, so is there a way to save without it prompting me. Thanks

```
Sub WordDocScrubber()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, i As Variant, dc As Document
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim security As MsoAutomationSecurity
    security = Application.AutomationSecurity
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable

    directory = "C:\Users\bayli\Desktop\Files for Testing\"
    fileName = Dir(directory & "*.do??")

    i = 0
    Do While fileName <> vbNullString
        On Error Resume Next
        Set dc = Documents.Open(directory & fileName)

        If Err.Number = 0 And Not dc Is Nothing Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            dc.RemoveDocumentInformation (wdRDIAll)
         dc.Close savechanges:=True,originalformat:=wdOriginalDocumentFormat
           'dc.Close savechanges:=True, originalformat:=wdWordDocument

            i = i + 1
            Application.StatusBar = "Files Completed:  " & i
            fileName = Dir()
        Else
            Err.Clear
            On Error GoTo 0
            'Handle 
        End If
    Loop

    Application.AutomationSecurity = security
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox "Complete"



End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have to resave them as .doc files, or can they be saved as .docx?

Comment: At what point in the code are you getting the prompt?

Comment: WHAT is the prompt? What's the message?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead to dc.close:

```
dc.Save
dc.Saved = True 'extra code, maybe not necessary
dc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It is absolutely correct. The trick is dc.Save. The middle line isn't needed.